# PHP View Counter

Tags: php, mysql, view, counter

I am trying to make a website and it's almost completed but I want to add a view counter so when someone visit the page it count the view and save it into the database. 
My script is working fine but the problem is that it continue view count even visitor is viewing anyother page

My pages url show like this
`pictures.php?ID=13`

**I have added this PHP code in **count.php****

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['views'])){
    $_SESSION['views']++;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['views'] =0;
        }
        //echo $_SESSION['views'];


?>
```

**Page **views.php****

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['$post_id'])){
    $_SESSION['$post_id']++;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['$post_id'] =0;
        }
        //echo $_SESSION['views'];


?>

<?php
    echo "<hr><div align=\"center\">";



    echo $_SESSION['$post_id'];
    ?>

    <?php
    $save = $_SESSION['$post_id'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","user");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE save_data SET Views='$save' WHERE ID='$page_id'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And added this line in Pictures.php where I want to show and count visits

```
<?php  include("views.php"); ?>
```

**Problem:**

When someone visits page `pictures.php?ID=8` it will show him page `view 1` and save this view in database where ID=8, when he visit page `pictures.php?ID=12` it will show him `view 2` and save this 2 in database where ID=12. My point is that it is continuously counting instead of each page view.

Thanks in advance

**Here is Pictures.php**

```
<?php 
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_GET['ID'])){

$page_id = $_GET['ID'];

    $select_query = "select * from save_data where ID='$page_id'";

$run_query = mysql_query($select_query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){

    $post_id = $row['ID']; 
    $post_title = $row['Title'];
    $post_image = $row['Name'];



?>

<h3>
<a href="pictures.php?ID=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">

<?php echo $post_title; ?>

</a>

</h3><center>
<form id="search-form" action="javascript:void(0);">
<input type="text" id="dimen" name="dimension" />
<input type="submit" value="Resize" Onclick ="splitString()"/></form>
<div id="sizet">
Type size like 200*300 in box
</div></center>

<div id="img"><img id="myImage" src="uploads/<?php echo $post_image; ?>"  /></div>



<?php } }?>
<center>
<div id="postdetails">
<?php  include("posted_by.php"); ?></center>
</div>
<?php  include("views.php"); ?>
<html>
<link href="css/Pictures.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function splitString()
{
var myDimen=document.getElementById("dimen").value;
var splitDimen = myDimen.split("*");
document.getElementById("myImage").width=splitDimen[0];
document.getElementById("myImage").height=splitDimen[1];
}
</script>
</head>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables inside of single quotes are not evaluated, so regardless of whether `$post_id` is 8 or 12, `$_SESSION['$post_id']` is setting the key named literally `$post_id`, rather than the key named `12` or `8`.  Variables are evaluated inside double quotes, so `$_SESSION["$post_id"]` would work, but the simplest and best way is to use `$_SESSION[$post_id]` instead.

Additionally, using $_SESSION here is probably not what you want to do. $_SESSION will be different for every user who visits the site, so when a new visitor comes to the site, it will start over with a count of 1. What you probably want to do is load the views value from the database, add one to it, and then save it back to the database. $_SESSION is for keeping data that is specific to a certain user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use structure like this

```
$_SESSION['view'][{resource_name}_{resource_id}]
```

E.g. for picture with id 8 it will be

```
$_SESSION['views']['picutures_8']++
```